# str_replace: Replace string with a function

Tags: php, str-replace

Just a simple question. I have a contact form stored in a function because it's just easier to call it on the pages I want it to have.

Now to extend usability, I want to search for {contactform} using str_replace.

Example:

```
function contactform(){
  // bunch of inputs
}

$wysiwyg = str_replace('{contactform}', contactform(), $wysiwyg);
```

So basically, if {contactform} is found. Replace it with the output of contactform.

Now I know that I can run the function before the replace and store its output in a variable, and then replace it with that same variable. But I'm interested to know if there is a better method than the one I have in mind.

Thanks

Comment: If the {contactform} doesn't appear most of the time it's better to use `preg_replace_callback` as suggested by @jedwards. If it's always there, your current code makes most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine, I would set it as a $var if you are planning to use the contents of contactform() more than once.

It might pay to use http://php.net/strpos to check if {contact_form} exists before running the str_replace function.

You could try both ways, and if your server support it, benchmark:

```
<?php echo 'Memory Usage: '. (!function_exists('memory_get_usage') ? '0' : round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024, 2)) .'MB'; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you *could* use PCRE and [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and then either modify your `contactform()` function or create a wrapper that accepts the matches.

I think your idea of running the function once and storing it in a variable makes more sense though.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at php's `call_user_func()` more information here http://php.net/call_user_func

```
$wysiwyg = 'Some string and {contactform}';

$find = '{contactform}'; 

strpos($wysiwyg, $find) ? call_user_func($find) : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is: Write one yourself. (Unless there already is one, which is always hard to be sure in PHP; see my next point.)

Ah, there it is: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Of course, it's one of the three regex libraries and as such, does not do simple string manipulation.

Anyway, my point is: Do not follow PHP's [non-]design guidelines. Write your own multibyte-safe string substitution function with a callback, and do not use `call_user_func()`.